# Ошибка при запуске .jar через консоль

Tags: java, spring, cmd, maven, jar

При запуске проекта через Idea он запускается отлично, без всяких ошибок. Но если собранный maven .jar попытаться открыть через консоль, он выдаёт ошибку(Приложил в скрине). Такое чувство что он не видит библиотек, или что-то в этом роде. Что это может быть?

Стектрейс ошибки:

2020-12-16 02:33:07.141 WARN [main] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'platformUnityHelperImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/project/turvo/utilities/utilities/utility/target/utility-service.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/turvo-unity-client-2.2.0.jar!/com/turvo/unity/service/platform/PlatformUnityHelperImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {} 2020-12-16 02:33:07.483 ERROR [main] org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по ошибке, вы не создали бин `restTemplate`, но при этом делаете его инжект. Чтобы понять почему он запускается в идее, необходима ссылка на код.